# Dropping a Pandas Row based on the prefix of value in a column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a Dataframe, `df` with a column called `Account Number`. I am trying to drop rows where the first two letters of the Account are 'AA' or 'BB'

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=["AA121", "AB1212", "BB121"],columns=['Account'])
print df
df = df[df['Account Number'][2:] not in ['AA', 'BB']]
```

Error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=["AA121", "AB1212", "BB121"],columns=['Account'])
print df
  Account
0   AA121
1  AB1212
2   BB121

print df['Account'].str[:2]
0    AA
1    AB
2    BB
Name: Account, dtype: object

print df['Account'].str[:2].str.contains('AA|BB')
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: Account, dtype: bool


df = df[~(df['Account'].str[:2].str.contains('AA|BB'))]
print df
  Account
1  AB1212
```

Or with [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
print ((df['Account'].str[:2].str.startswith('AA')) |
        (df['Account'].str[:2].str.startswith('BB')))
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: Account, dtype: bool

print ~((df['Account'].str[:2].str.startswith('AA')) |
        (df['Account'].str[:2].str.startswith('BB')))
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: Account, dtype: bool

df = df[~((df['Account'].str[:2].str.startswith('AA')) | 
          (df['Account'].str[:2].str.startswith('BB')))]
print df
  Account
1  AB1212
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the ~ doing?

Comment: It functions like `not` does, inverting the boolean mask.

Comment: I add sample for `~`